# Dplyr: Create two columns based on specific conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

In this dataset DF, we have 4 names and 4 professions.

```
DF<-tribble(
    ~names, ~princess, ~singer, ~astronaut, ~painter,
    "diana",   4,  1,  2, 3,
    "shakira",   2,  1, 3, 4,
    "armstrong",   3, 4, 1, 2,
    "picasso",  1, 3, 1, 4
)
```

Assume that the cell values are some measure of their their profession. So, for instance, Diana has highest cell value for princess (correctly) but Shakira has highest cell value for painter (incorrectly).

I want to create two columns called "Compatible" and "Incompatible" where the program will pick value of 4 for Diana as it is under the correct profession Princess and assign it to column "Compatible" and in the "Incompatible" put an average of the other 3 values. For Shakira, it will pick the value 1 from the correct profession of singer, and assign it to Compatible; for Incompatible it average the other values. Similarly for other names

So the output will be like this:

```
DF1<-tribble(
        ~names, ~princess, ~singer, ~astronaut, ~painter,~Compatible,~Incompatible,
        "diana",   4,  1,  2, 3, 4, 2,
        "shakira",   2,  1, 3, 4, 1, 3,
        "armstrong",   3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3,
        "picasso",  1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1.66
    )
```

Here is the dataset which shows the correct names and professions:

```
DF3<- tribble(
    ~names, ~professions,
    "diana",  "princess",
    "shakira",  "singer",
    "armstrong",  "astronaut",
    "picasso", "painter"
)
```

Comment: How do you know the correct profession? Do you have a dataframe that lists the correct profession for each person

Comment: I do, but for this dataset: Diana is princess, shakira is singer, armstrong is astronaut, picasso is painter

Comment: Then include that dataframe in your question with names and profession

Comment: @KU99 I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF1[1:5] %>%
  pivot_longer(-names) %>%
  left_join(DF3, 'names') %>%
  group_by(names, name = if_else(name == professions, 'compatible', 'incompatible')) %>%
  summarise(profession = first(professions), value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  names     profession compatible incompatible
  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>
1 armstrong astronaut           1         3   
2 diana     princess            4         2   
3 picasso   painter             4         1.67
4 shakira   singer              1         3
```

Comment: thanks but the incompatible means do not look correct.

Comment: @user10193929 ITS BECAUSE I took them already. Check the edit